# Getting clients on Dribbble?

Tags: portfolio, client-relations, dribbble

I've done some googling and I'm trying to get a feel for how Dribbble pans out with getting new clients. Has it worked for any of you? Did it result in a certain amount of your total yearly income, or has it been a bust?

I'm trying to see if I should invest my time and money into presenting myself on that site and see if it's likely to yield some gigs.

Comment: 'I'm trying to see if I should invest my time and money into presenting myself' I think the pro option is a little over 1,5 bucks, and I assume that as a designer you already have a portfolio of some sort, so the effort can't be *that* big.

Comment: Have you ever tried to format your graphic design work for their ridiculous 400x300 size? That's a PITA.

Answer (score 3):

As it has been stated, Dribbble isn't as popular as it once was but that doesn't mean you shouldn't treat it like any other social media platform.  If you plan it correctly and have your own site you regularly update you could script your portfolio work so it makes it easier to push to social media.

For example, I do more web design.  So after I complete a web design I will run a script that will screen capture the site at different sizes. If I build an icon set, I set everything in a default Illustrator template and I run JavaScript on it that exports certain sizes and looks.  I will go through and pick the ones I like and then push to social media.

For me I like to think of it as building teaser content to draw more attention to a site.  I do notice more people wanting to collaborate on projects through Dribbble which is always a good backup to either building a personal project or keeping in touch with some that you know if you get busy you can outsource some work.

Answer (score 1):

I've not had any work from there exactly, but I have had a few people getting in touch with me as a result of me uploading work on there.

The most notable ones were an offer for a job interview and also an email from a guy from Coca-Cola... sadly he never got back to me after I responded for some reason.

Dribbble seems like one of those communities that isn't as popular as it used to be IMO... e.g. sometimes I'll search for something in particular, and see that most of the results are from around 5–6 years ago. Yet despite this I do still get the odd email as a result of posting a bunch of work on there.